# DARLE FORMATO DE HORA A COLUMNA DE EXCEL AL DESCARGARLA CON PHPSPREADSHEET

Tags: php, excel, phpspreadsheet

Tengo un problema, al descargar un reporte en excel generado con PHPSPREADSHEET y querer ordenar las columnas por hora, me las detecta como cadena de texto, como puedo hacer para darles formato de hora, e intentado lo siguiente:

```
$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('D')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('E')
->getNumberFormat()
->setFormatCode(\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_TIME3);
```

Desde base de datos probé trayendo la data de esas columnas como time y como char, y con ningun tipo de dato me funciona.

Este es el error cuando trato de ordenar por hora en excel.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yWemL.png]

Alguien a tenido un problema similar o tiene alguna solución, me ayudaría mucho.

Comment: En Excel, las horas es un número con decimales. La parte entera es la fecha en sí y la decimal el tiempo en horas. Primero, asegúrate que de verdad estás volcando un dato que es un número (nada de espacios en blanco al principio o al final). Segundo, prueba a multiplicar todas las horas por 1, para que Excel las convierta a numérico sin cambiar el valor.

Comment: Intentaré hacerlo, como solución rápida lo solucioné armando el excel desde html y no con phpspreadsheet, pero trataré de usar lo que me dices, gracias.